# Map letter-number combination into command in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to define a mapping to yank lines upwards without moving.
I need a mapping from `y[Number]k` to `:-[Number]y<CR>`.

For example, if i wanted to yank 6 lines upwards, i would type `y6k` and it would be mapped to `:-6,y`. Is this possible in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
nnoremap <expr> <key> ":\<C-u>-" . v:count1 . ",y\<CR>"
```

that lets you do `{count}<key>` as if you did `y{count}k` or `:-{count},y`.